# HAPROXY 2.8 drain mode is not working

Tags: haproxy

I'm running HAPROXY 2.8 on ubuntu 22.02.4 LTS,
I want to put "svr01" in drain mode, I tried all of the following commands but it didn't work!

```
echo "set server app/svr01 state drain" | socat stdio /var/lib/haproxy/stats

echo "set server backend/svr01 state drain" | sudo socat stdio /etc/haproxy/haproxysock

echo "set server backend/svr01 weight 0" | sudo socat stdio /etc/haproxy/haproxysock

set server backend/svr01 state [ drain ]
```

While running the command

```
echo "set server app/svr01 state drain" | socat stdio /var/lib/haproxy/stats
```

on HAPROXY 1.9.4 is working fine, any idea!

Comment: Why are you using random paths to the socket and random backend/server names?  Check your config for the socket path and backend/server names.